# Building Caliburn.Micro, getting "The specified language targets for uap10.0.16299 is missing"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, caliburn.micro

I've cloned the Caliburn.Micro repository and want to build it, but I'm getting this error for both the Core and Platform projects:

> The specified language targets for uap10.0.16299 is missing. Ensure correct tooling is installed for 'uap'. Missing: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets'    Caliburn.Micro.Platform C:\Users\username.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.1.2\Build\LanguageTargets\CheckMissing.targets

I have installed the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.4), the latest .NET SDK (5.0.102), and a bunch of components for Visual Studio, (.NET frameworks, Windows 10 SDK:s). but nothing helps to resolve the issue.

Looking under dependencies for the projects it seems that uap10.0.16299 is missing. But I've specifically installed Windows 10 SDK for 16299, but no difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: SDK differs for each build. Is [16299 SDK installed via VS Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606326/1466046)?

Comment: Yes, i used the installer. Also, I don't seem to be able to change the target Windows version under Application in the project properties. I only get an empty, disabled target framework dropdown.

Comment: you will need the minimum uwp version to be 16299.  what happens when you look at the windows version in the project properties?  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1483513/92914873-09340880-f3fa-11ea-8fe5-3b117c3d1e92.png

Comment: I can't. I don't see target version of windows, but rather target framework as for a .net framework project. https://pasteboard.co/JKfj9cc.png

Comment: I've selected these in the installer https://pasteboard.co/JKfD08u.png

Comment: Use visual studio 2019 instead of 2017.  I am using the vs 2019 community edition.  I have UWP 16299 and newer installed.  I also have .net 5 and .net core 3.1 installed.  If you have an issue with any of the projects loading take a look at this blog post. https://vb2ae.github.io/2020/09/13/The-path-is-not-a-legal-form-when-opening-a-project.html

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I've installed .Net Core 3.1 as well as 5 (even though 5 is backwards compatible). But unfortunately it did not help. Still have the same error. Maybe it's some esoteric bug on my computer causing this to manifest. I I've tried everything suggested.

Comment: Interesting the I selected these in the installer pic showed it was vs 2017

Comment: Ouch! I was installing some components for the Visual Studio Build Tools 2017! Somehow I missed that they switched place in the installer. Now I've installed the 16299 target for Visual Studio 2019, but it's still not working... still unable to switch target in the core project.